# String assign(not at time of declaration) in string matrix

Tags: c

I have created this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
   char str[1][10][4];
   str[1][1]="YES";
   str[1][2]="NO";

   printf("%s",str[1][1]);
   getch();
}
```

str is a matrix which have 1 row and 10 columns.
but this program shows error.

I want to **assign**(not scan) value to each field like this

```
 str[1][1]   str[1][2]   str[1][3]..........
    YES          NO         YES
```

Please suggest me any way.

Comment: It should be `str[0][0], str[0][1]`...

Comment: `"YES"` will not fit in `char [3]` -- you need +1 for the *nul-terminating* character. (and get rid of `conio.h` and `getch()` and simply use `getchar()` to hold the terminal window open on windows -- `conio.h` and `getch()` are 100% non-portable)

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
char str[10][4] = { "Yes", "No", "Yes", /* ... */ };
```

Be aware that you need one array position more for the trailing null character!

As shown above, additional (unassigned) values are set to 0, so you'd get empty strings if not sufficient initialisers provided.

By the way, you *can* drop first array parameter, below a variant doing so *and* using designated initialisers:

```
char str[][4] = { [0] = "Yes", [7] = "Yes", [10] = "No", [12] = "No", /* ... */ };
```

Again, unsigned values are 0, outer array length is number of entries (if no designated initialisers used) or long enough to include highest index provided (so size is highest index + 1).

*Edit: Assigning at a later point of time:*

```
char str[10][4];
// ...
memcpy(str[7], "Yes", sizeof("Yes"));
```

Be aware that you can apply `sizeof` *only* to string *literals* – for strings received via a *pointer* you must use `strlen` instead (the latter not counting the terminating null character, though, which `sizeof` does).

Note that I deliberately did not use `strcpy` because if length is known, memcpy is more efficient, and if not known, `strcpy` is unsafe (risking undefined behaviour due to writing beyond target array bounds).

If you use pointers, the matter gets easier:

```
char const* const YES = "Yes"; // constants for safer usage
char const* const NO  = "No";

char const* str[10]; // array of pointers, not array of arrays

str [7] = NO;
```

Of course, you still can pre-initialise:

```
char const* str[10] = { YES, NO, YES, NO, /* ... */ };
```

Comment: i do  not  want to assign  values initially .what if i have to assign seperately like str[1] ="Yes" .you are assigning initially at the time of declaration .but i want to assign at different time

Comment: `strcpy(a,b)` is less error-prone and more readable than `memcpy(a, b, sizeof b)`.If the length is not known then neither version is appropriate, and if the length is known the compiler will optimize it. (and even if it didn't, this is an extreme micro-optimization that's relevant to almost nobody)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `str` represents a block in the memory of size 1*10*3 bytes (size of `char`). What your code tries to do is to assign a character pointer (`char*`) to an array (`str[1][1]` is an one-dimensional array), which makes no sense.

So the basic answer is that you need to use e.g. `strncpy` to copy the bytes from the string "YES" or "NO" to the array.

Also note that

1. Line `str[1][1]="YES"` lacks a semicolon `;` at the end
2. Your array dimensions have no space for the null terminator of the string ("YES" is actually "YES\0")
3. You seem to start indices from 1 instead of 0, which you in general should not do, because in C the first index is 0, not 1

Comment: regarding point 1, the missing semicolon is less of a problem than the fact that you can't use `=` to assign to arrays anyway.  Also `strncpy` is unsafe in that sometimes it does not null-terminate the output

Answer (score 0):

1st of all in C arry indexing is 0-based. So you most likley do not want

> ```
> str[1][1]   str[1][2]   str[1][3]
>
> YES         NO          YES
> ```

but

> ```
> str[0][0]   str[0][1]   str[0][2]
>
> YES         NO          YES
> ```

To achieve this you have three possibilities.

1. As arrays cannot be assigned, copy the array's content.

   Define a 2D array of array of `char` with size 4 and copy whatever is less then 4 `char`long into them

   ```
   char str[1][10][4];
   strcpy(str[0][0], "YES");
   strcpy(str[0][1], "NO");
   strcpy(str[0][2], "YES");
   strcpy(str[0][3], "BAR");
   ```

   You can later change each `char` separately:

   ```
   strcpy(str[0][0][0] = '1'; /* gives you "1ES" */
   strcpy(str[0][2][0] = '3'; /* gives you "2ES" */
   ```
2. If you only need to use `"YES"` and `"NO"` you can define them once, and make your array a 2D array of pointer to `char` and let its entries refer to the value defined before:

   ```
   char yes[] = "YES";
   char no[] = "NO";

   char * str[1][10];
   str[0][0] = yes;
   str[0][1] = no;
   str[0][2] = yes;
   ```

   If you later change a `char` for one it changes the value of all:

   ```
   strcpy(str[0][0][0] = '1'; /* gives you "1ES" for str[0][0] and str[0][2] */

   strcpy(str[0][2][0] = '2'; /* gives you "2ES" for str[0][0] and
   ```
3. If you do not want to change the strings's characters separately then define them as under 2. above but define them as pointers to constant by doing:

   ```
   char * yes = "YES";
   char * no = "NO";

   char * str[1][10];
   str[0][0] = yes;
   str[0][1] = no;
   str[0][2] = yes;
   ```

   You cannot later change a `char`.